# Build App for iPad, that exists in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, class, screen, core-plot

I built an App with the CorePlot framework for iPhone. I implemented 3 classes with 3 different charts, each one with is own screen. Now i want to built the same App for iPad, which is my first app for this device.

On the iPad, i want to show all 3 charts in the same screen, but i want to keep it modular. How do i do this? Any suggestions?

Comment: what are the 3 classes you created? please add more details regarding your app design...

Comment: I followed this tutorial to build my app, so the 3 classes are these http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically you have three separate controllers that you display within a tab bar controller on the iPhone.

What you could do to show the 3 graphs together in a view and keep the design modular is:

1. create a containing controller;
2. in `viewDidLoad`, create your 3 graphs controllers and then do:

   ```
   [self.view addSubview:graphController1.view];
   [self.view addSubview:graphController2.view];
   [self.view addSubview:graphController2.view];
   ```
3. in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` relay those messages to the 3 sub-controllers;
4. do the same as in 3. for autorotation methods.

This approach will work for all iOS versions.

If you are targeting iOS>5, you can use [UIViewController Containment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), where you can define your 3 controllers as child controllers of your main controller and add/remove them at will.